# How do I pass a char(*)([long unsigned int]) as a parameter in C?

Tags: c, parameters, char

I have a variable type:

```
char (*p)[12] = calloc(n, sizeof(*p));
```

I need the variable to stay this way, but I am having trouble passing it as a parameter due to the function type giving me errors:

```
void myMethod(char *p) { ... }
```

What can I use in myMethod as the parameter to make this work?

Comment: I think your intention may have been to use `char* p[12]` instead of what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same type for the parameter as you did for the variable:

```
void myMethod(char (*p)[12])
{
  // do something with p
}
...
char (*p)[12] = calloc(n, sizeof *p);
myMethod(p);
```

Remember that `p` is a pointer to a 12-element array of `char`, not a simple pointer to `char`.  Thus, the type of `p[i]` will be `char [12]` (which in most cases will decay to `char *`).

Answer (score 4):

> What can I use in myMethod as the parameter to make this work

Possibly this:

```
void myMethod(char (*p)[12])
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical C idiom is to pass a `char*` and a `size_t` (or `unsigned int` or whatever equivalent) parameter. Then the contract of the function is that it will respect the `size_t` argument as the length of the array/buffer.

If you must insist that the pointer be not changed, you use the `const` qualifier.

Comment: This is true in the general case, bit I think this may be cleaner without the size_t since the array size is constant

Answer (score -2):

```
char (*p)[12] = ...
```

With the previous you have ***NOT*** defined an array of 12 elements, each one being a pointer to char ***BUT*** a pointer to an array with 12 char elements.

As explained in the following lines:

```
int *a[3];
```

Start at a . Look right, say array of size 3. Look left and say pointer. Look right and see nothing. Look left and say int. All together you say a is an array of size 3 pointers to int.

Adding parentheses is when it gets weird:

```
int (*a)[3];
```

The parentheses change the order just like in an expression. When you look right after a , you see the right parenthesis, which you cannot jump over until you look left. Hence, you would say a is a pointer to an array of 3 ints.

Check these links for better explanation:

- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations
- http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/reading-c-declarations.html

---

Still if you want to pass the array to a function you can either copy it, or since it is an array pass a pointer to the first element (you can simply do it by using the name of the array):

```
myMethod( p ) <- how you call the function
```

I personally would prefer the latter case, since you're passing to the function a simple pointer and not an array by copy of all of its elements

Comment: No - he has declared `p` as a pointer to a 12-element array of `char`, not an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: @JohnBode - thks for letting me notice..I just went against a wall!But hey, I just proved that you can learn also from answers!